# VSC Java Build Status stop

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Hi my vsc is stuck loading Java Plugins and doesn't highlight bugs in the code. How can I solve my problem?

List of plugins related to Java:

- Debugger for Java
- Java Extension Pack
- Java Test Runner
- Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat
- Maven for Java
- Project Manager for Java

Java Build Status info:

```
8d74ad46 Configuring java project test-app: 68% Refreshing '/test-app/src/main/java'. [684/1000]
7b0ee4ba Reporting encoding changes. [Done]
037e4b50 Register Watchers [Done]
```

Has anyone had this problem before ?

Comment: May I know if you reached my answer？ Does it help you？

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug in v0.80.0, see this report:

[Try to run normal spring boot project on win 10 with JDK 16 It will stuck on 68%](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2020)

The current useful workaround is installing another version: [java-0.80.2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/snjeza/vscode-test/master/java-0.80.2.vsix) or rolling back to `0.79.2`.

Have a try and see if the question goes away.

Comment: I went to Extensions tab, clicked ellipsis, and "Install from VSIX". The 0.80.2 fixed the "68%" issue. However, later I noticed that "Quick Fix..." functionality broke, specifically it no longer offered to import anything. And there were some other issues. Then I reverted to 0.80.0 and the "68%" issue does not occur anymore. HTH

Comment: @Terry. Reinstallation solves your question :)

Comment: it`s Ok now to try rollback to 0.79.2.

Comment: @suiwenfeng. Yes, the original post who put the github issue also solved the question by rolling back to 0.79.2.